# Get error "Your connection to this site is not private!" after I separated host from SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ssl, dns, host

I have an ASP.NET MVC with Entity and SQL Server DB that were all installed on a local host in China and got a domain (www.mykrone.net) from GoDaddy. After a while we faced with a funny problem that the China telecommunication organization (or so) didn't let us to use port 80 !!!. So we got a SSL (port 443) certificate and set it.

It worked well but I decided to separate the website from SQL. So I got a new host in another country and moved website files there but DB was still in china (on a local host). I just stopped IIS in China and started new website on new host.

Sorry for this long story...

After all those changes site uploaded but now in some parts when I want to fetch data from DB it gets below error:

```
"Your connection to this site is not private"
```

[This is what Chrome shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kS93M.jpg)

After searching I released that when I try to fetch from tables in SQL it's good but once I want to use a view with different schema like "web" the error happens even though my ConnectionString uses "sa" user!

I'll be so thankful if enybody know the solution.

Comment: can you post your connection string ?

Comment: Yeah sure:<add name="Test_DbContext" connectionString="Data Source=?.?.?.?;Initial Catalog=test;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=pass" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: Was that helpful Sagar?!

Comment: please check the answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<add name="Test_00" connectionString="Data Source=?.?.?.?; database=Sample; User ID=username;Password=password";MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Sorry it didn't work. So What do you think this about?

Comment: if you are using Chrome browser than this link will help you,
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6098869?hl=en#connection

Comment: I added a pic of error to the question, it might help. But it happens in all browsers.

Comment: It happens in all browsers.

Comment: Sorry ! Can't help beyond this,you should create ticket at GoDaddy and ask them about this issue,if already done than what was the reply?